# Why this ajax call is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.clickthetext').click(function(){

        $.post("submit.php", $("#formbox").serialize(),  function(response) {
            $('#content').html(response);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

My target to pass content from the form and edit the data and show response at current page.

**.clickthetext** button content:

```
<div class="clickthetext">Click here to see the result</div>
```

content inside id **#formbox**:
Part of the form inside this id. rest of the form is out side this id will be processed later. only content/input inside of id "formbox" will be processed.

Whatever response we will get, we will show inside of "#content" id.

What i am doing wrong here?

----edit----

i didn't add anything on submit.php
only to show response, i wrote there:

```
<?php
 echo 'somthing blah blah blah something';
?>
```

Comment: Is ajax request sent? Is it successful?

Comment: where is the `submit.php` which is called by this ajax?

Comment: @Ghost, submit.php is in the same folder.

Comment: Please post the submit.php code

Comment: @crazymoin what i mean is, you should include this in your question. since its related to this request. just one typo in PHP will derail this request

Comment: @Ghost, on php file i wrote only: <?php echo 'this is response'; ?>. this is only for testing

Comment: @crazymoin well if thats the case, they just open your console browser and check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a problem with the result of `submit.php`

You can try calling

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.clickthetext').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          data: $("#formbox").serialize(),
          success: function(response) {  $('#content').html(response); },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); },
          dataType: dataType
});
        return false;
    });

});
```

instead and get more detail of the result of the ajax call.

[Here's the API for the ajax object in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: It's possible to check the Network connections even with original code.

Answer (score 0):

Recreating your set up,

**JS/HTML**

```
<form action="" id="formbox">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="First Name">
</form>
<button class="clickthetext">Button</button>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $('.clickthetext').click(function() {
            $.post("submit.php", $("#formbox").serialize(), function (response) {
                $('#content').html(response);
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

**PHP:** submit.php

```
<?php echo 'this is the response'; ?>
```

Everything works perfectly.

Debugging tips:

1) Most likely - Check your javascript console for any errors. You probably have errors elsewhere in the page.

2) Ensure you're accessing the HTML page with the javascript via localhost, not a filepath

3) Unlikely, but check your PHP log.